# Error Unziping a file - Jupyter Notebook - Python 2.x -3.x - AI Notebook -Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I am attempting to download a .zip file from https://www.fec.gov/data/browse-data/?tab=bulk-data specifically https://www.fec.gov/files/bulk-downloads/2020/indiv20.zip. Compressed, the file is 2.7 GB. The download is initiated and complete within 10 seconds. When I then try to unzip the file, I receive the error messages below. When downloaded to my local machine, the link downloads as a .zip file and opens to the data requested.

```
!python --version
```

`Python 3.7.8`

```
!curl -O https://www.fec.gov/files/bulk-downloads/2020/indiv20.zip
```

`% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100   138  100   138    0     0    690      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   690`

```
!unzip -a indiv20.zip
```

`Archive:  indiv20.zip End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on the last disk(s) of this archive. unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of indiv20.zip or indiv20.zip.zip, and cannot find indiv20.zip.ZIP, period.`

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile("indiv20.zip", 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the HTTP server is returning a redirection and `curl` is storing the "302 Found" message into the indiv20.zip file instead of the actual ZIP data.

You can solve this by adding the `-L` (or [--location](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)) parameter to the `curl` command so it follows redirects:

```
$ curl -LO https://www.fec.gov/files/bulk-downloads/2020/indiv20.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of the file. It is probably an error message in html. (cat indiv20.zip)